# Neural network returns nan

Tags: python, keras

Why sometimes neural network cant predict values and return [nan...nan] in simple regression task?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.asarray([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=1,activation = 'linear'))
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=1,activation = 'linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1,activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=20)
X2 = np.array([10,11,12])
print(model.predict(X2))
```

Comment: I try 100, 200 epoches and sometimes get [nan...nan]

Comment: A few possibilities to get you started: sometimes the implementations of the loss functions will yield strange results if the type of the inputs and outputs isn't correct. Your X array is type integer, your y array is type float. I doubt this is the cause as the output of the Dense layers is likely float but could be worth trying. Also possible is that the learning rate on the stochastic gradient descent is too high so the loss bounces around and amplifies before eventually becoming too large to evaluate, resulting in NaN.

Comment: @DerekG big thanks!! Decrease of learning rate solved this problem!!